# Sharing manager list with threads and process creates seperate copies

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to share a list between the processes and threads. So I found the `multiprocessing.Manager()` for creating a list. I wrote the following piece of code:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time

def consumer(l):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 20:
        time.sleep(5)
        l = l[len(l)/2:]
        print "consumer l: {}".format(l)
        counter += 5

def producer(l):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(i)
        l.append(i)
        print "producer l: {}".format(l)

if __name__=="__main__":
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    l = mgr.list()

    p = threading.Thread(target=producer, args=(l,))
    c = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args=(l,))

    p.start()
    c.start()

    p.join()
    c.join()
    print "done"
```

It creates a process and a thread sharing a list created by manager. Producer appends to the list after every i seconds while consumer halves the list every 5 seconds. I expected that the lists would be same and both will be operating on it. But I observe that consumer and producer share the list only once and next time the lists are seperated.

Output observed:

```
producer l: [0]
producer l: [0, 1]
producer l: [0, 1, 2]
consumer l: [1, 2]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
consumer l: [2]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
consumer l: [2]
consumer l: [2]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
producer l: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
done
```

What should be done so that both of them uses same list throughout?

Comment: Use multiprocessing Queue module to share the tasks, don't use normal data structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
    l = l[len(l)/2:]
```

It looks ok, but what it actually does is that it creates a new copy of `l` and assigns `l` to this new object. This means the variables diverge at your first consumer execution, and the `l` in consumer is no longer bound to the `l` passed to it.

Consider this version of your consumer:

```
def consumer(l):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 20:
        time.sleep(5)
        n = len(l)/2
        for _ in range(0,n+1):
            try:
                l.pop()
            except IndexError:
                pass
        print "consumer l: {}".format(l)
        counter += 5
```

It is not elegant and it probably is not quite what you are looking for, but I have replaced assigning `l` to a new instance with list manipulation methods (pop in this case). As long as you keep modifying your `l` with list management methods like `pop`, `append`, `insert` or `remove`, you are fine.

NB your producer would be suffering from the same problem if you assigned there `l` to something new, but you already have `l.append()` there, so that part is fine.

Comment: Thank @Hannu. It helped. I have also added an answer which uses `del` to remove the items from the list

Answer (score 1):

I changed the program to:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time

def consumer(l):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 20:
        time.sleep(5)
        del l[0 : len(l)/2+1]                                                                                                                                                   
        print("consumer l address {}".format(hex(id(l))))
        print "consumer l: {}".format(l)
        counter += 5

def producer(l):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(i)
        print("producer l address {}".format(hex(id(l))))
        l.append(i)
        print "producer l: {}".format(l)

if __name__=="__main__":
    mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    l = mgr.list()

    print("list address {}".format(hex(id(l))))
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer, args=(l,))
    c = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer, args=(l,))

    p.start()
    c.start()

    p.join()
    c.join()
    print "done"
```

Notice that I have used `del` instead of creating a new list and assigning it to the old one. I have also added address printing statements in the above code. If you run it as it is, you should see that the address of the list remains same everywhere as we are not recreating the list. If you change line number 9 back to `l = l[len(l)/2:]` and run the program, you should notice that the address of the lists for the consumer and producer changes after the first operation.